# Specific page security on web.config

Tags: asp.net, security, web-config

I have the following on my web.config

```
<location path = "WebPages/Reports">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny roles="DeniedRole1, DeniedRole2"/>
            <allow roles="AllowRole1,AllowRole2,AllowRole3"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<location path = "WebPages/Reports/SpecificPage.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles ="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is for everyone to have access to the SpecificPage.aspx, but for any other page inside the Reports folder it should apply the deny/allow rules. However, this is giving me the following error:

```
Parser Error Message: Authorization rule names cannot contain the '*' character.
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Make a http module for your authorization/authentication then you have much more control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<location path = "WebPages/Reports/SpecificPage.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Getting the same error, I think I partially fixed it by replacing * with ALL the roles but I'm still trying to figure out why it won't let me.